# Module Name not coming while adding opencv in Android Sudio 4.1.0 and opencv version 4.1.0

Tags: android-studio, opencv

I am a beginner at android app development or you can say this is my first android App. I want to import opencv in my android app,  but while importing it's not showing in my app. Below is the screenshot for it.

I know, I have seen many tutorials but I don't know why I am not able to get it for me.

This is how it should come.
[Module Import Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfyQj.png)

This is what I am getting.

[My Module import page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAy0m.png)

In project structure also, I am not getting as expected.

[In project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPVtH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `build.gradle` for OpenCVLibraryxxx. Since you are using it as a library, sometimes it defined as application.

```
//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

And also delete  `applicationId "org.opencv"` from `defaultConfig` part.